# Sampling from a bounded domain zipf distribution

Tags: python, distribution, probability, sampling

I'd like to sample from "zipf" distribution from a bounded domain.

That is, assume that the domain is {1,...,N}, I'd like each element in the domain, i, to be chosen with probability proportional to `i ** -a`, where `a` is a parameter of the distribution.

`numpy` provides a zipf sampler (numpy.random.zipf), but it does not allow me to restrict the domain.

> **How can I easily sample from such distribution?**

---

If the distribution parameter, `a`, is larger than 1, I can use the `numpy` sampler by rejecting (and re-sampling) all samples larger than `N`. However, since it does not restrict the sample range, trying to use any smaller values of `a` does not work.

When the domain is finite, there shouldn't be a problem to use such `a`s, and that is what I need for my application.

Comment: @unutbu - yes, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `scipy.stats`, you could create a custom discrete distribution:

```
bounded_zipf = stats.rv_discrete(name='bounded_zipf', values=(x, weights))
```

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 7
x = np.arange(1, N+1)
a = 1.1
weights = x ** (-a)
weights /= weights.sum()
bounded_zipf = stats.rv_discrete(name='bounded_zipf', values=(x, weights))

sample = bounded_zipf.rvs(size=10000)
plt.hist(sample, bins=np.arange(1, N+2))
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If sampling performance is an issue, you could implement your own sampling method based on rejection-inversion sampling. You will find a corresponding Java implementation [here](https://github.com/apache/commons-math/blob/138f84bfa5d36c8f6e2825640af1ed82daa9dc1d/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math4/distribution/ZipfDistribution.java).